# How to get following result for my SQL?

Tags: sql, relationship, unique-constraint, query-by-example

My Employee Table

```
EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEENAME
```

My CallReportEmployee Table

```
ReportID, EMPLOYEEID
```

My Report Table

```
ReportID , ReportName
```

When I want to get is I want to show all the employee name, when those didnt choose ReportID 1

1 report can consist of many employees

How can I such outcome is I want to list out all the Employee with ReportID one and not 1?

```
EMPLOYEENAME    REPORTID
Roger              1
Peter              1
Shawn             NULL
Peter             NULL
```

I try this, it didn't work

```
SELECT rc.EmployeeID, rc.ReportID, e.FirstName
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN callreportemployee rc ON e.ID = rc.EmployeeID
```

it just show all the employee

```
EMPLOYEENAME    REPORTID
Roger             Null
Peter              1
Peter              2
Shawn              3
Shawn              2
John             NULL
```

if i add in in a `where rc.ReportID = 1` it become show Peter only

How can I achieve the format I want? I don't want duplicate Name

Comment: If I understand your question right you want the values with NULL and 1? If so, just change the WHERE clause to an extra condition in the ON

Comment: can I get values of 3 & 2? can I make them appear as NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I achieve the format I want? I don't want duplicate Name

Use the `GROUP BY` clause to aggregate the duplicate names, as in this query:

```
SELECT U.Id as [User Link], Count(Pt.Id) AS ANSWERS
FROM Users U, Posts P, PostHistory Ph, PostTypes Pt
WHERE
Pt.Id = Ph.PostHistoryTypeId
AND
U.Id = P.OwnerUserId
AND
P.Id = Ph.PostId
AND
Pt.Id = 2
GROUP BY U.Id
HAVING Count(Pt.Id) > 2000
ORDER BY ANSWERS DESC
```

**References**

- [Users with over 2000 Answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/138197/users-with-over-2000-answers)